# Deleting element from OrderedMap and keeping its order

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I want to create Map which has key and value, and keep order of elements inside of it.

That order defines an order of displaying elements on the screen.

Also, I want to have possibility to delete one of the elements and keep their order.

And the most important think I'm using immutable.js library and I want to use it. Can I do it with that library?

That is what I tested:

```
const { OrderedMap } = require("immutable");

let test = OrderedMap({ 
    a: 10, 
    b: 20, 
    c: 30, 
    d: 40
});

test = test.delete('b');

console.log(test);
```

And it prints me this: 
[image: IMG]

I was expecting a, c, d order but i get a, d, c.

**UPDATED**

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/40gc3d6y/)

[image: Console - what I've got]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [repo](https://github.com/Asday/immutablejs-delete-from-ordered-map/tree/5c09891c849042a3c8c0fb0fc7ce036c8b98cd6b) to reproduce your issue, but was unable to.

I added a `console.log()` before deleting the item, to make sure `test` had keys in the right order before I modified it.  Here is my output:

```
~/code/src/github.com/asday/immutablejs-delete-from-ordered-map $ node index.js
OrderedMap { "a": 10, "b": 20, "c": 30, "d": 40 }
OrderedMap { "a": 10, "c": 30, "d": 40 }
```

It's possible that the environment you're running the code in is not respecting the order of the keys provided to `OrderedMap()`.  If this is the case, try instantiating it with an array of `[key, value]` pairs:

```
let test = OrderedMap([
    ['a', 10],
    ['b', 20],
    ['c', 30],
    ['d', 40],
]);
```

And see if that fixes your issue.

---

EDIT:  Your problem is you're attempting to use the internals of the `OrderedMap`, whereas you should be using methods defined on it.  The order of what's in `._map` is irrelevant, as you can see:

```
> test.toString()
"OrderedMap { "a": 10, "c": 30, "d": 40 }"
```

If you want to iterate over your values in order, you should use `.map()` like so:

```
test.map((x) => console.log(x))
```

Or:

```
test.mapEntries((x) => console.log(x[0], x[1]))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I tried here https://npm.runkit.com/immutable. My immutable version is 3.8.2 and yours?

Comment: Please update your question with the environment you're running the code in, and perhaps a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net) demonstrating it, so I can investigate further.

Comment: Edited main topic.

Comment: Edited my answer.